# Selenium WebDriver, UnreachableBrowserException when I run tests on Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, webdriver

I have UnreachableBrowserException when I run my tests on Firefox 14. On IE9 and Chrome tests runs fine. What it mean and how to fix it?
Thanks for any answer.

```
FAILED CONFIGURATION: @AfterClass tearDown
org.openqa.selenium.remote.UnreachableBrowserException: Error communicating with the remote browser. It may have died.
Build info: version: '2.24.1', revision: '17205', time: '2012-06-19 16:53:24'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.6.0_25'
Driver info: driver.version: RemoteWebDriver
```

I want to add that sometimes console displays this exception and sometimes I have exception `NoSuchElementException` because driver found select component, but didn't found suggest option. On IE and Chrome there is no problem, because element and option is always found.

Answer (score 1):

The last time we had this, the reason was, a "closed" driver.
Because of bad implementation, we closed the driver in the "@After" and not in the "@AfterClass".
With the Chrome-Driver it worked fine, but with FF it failed.

Check if the "close" comes before the @AfterClass is called.

Comment: Yes, I have @AfterClass addnotation above function with driver.close()

Answer (score 1):

Update your selenium to version [2.25](http://seleniumhq.org/download/), which should be compatible with FF 14.

Comment: actually I installed FF 12, and now it's ok, so probably you advice was right

Answer (score 0):

selenium version 3.5

Also check the combination of the following are not configured:

```
System.setProperty( "webdriver.gecko.driver" ,"C:/PATH_TO_selenium/geckodriver.exe" );
```